# How to remove strange a/img border or underline after drag or click de image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

For understand de problem please, look the image or access the website: http://www.crishk.com/ click in the top image logo, and you will see that strange underline or border below the logo.

When you click the image and drag the mouse to another part of the page, then drop it and return to the logo and you move the mouse over the image you will see that border/underline there too.

Can you help? It only appears on Chrome. [image]

Comment: Give `outline:none` to anchor tag wrapping the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this styles in your style sheet

```
.topmessage a{
    outline : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a text-decoration on 'a' tag

```
<a href="http://www.crishk.com" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <img width="250" height="55" border="0" src="/images/toplogo.png">
</a>
```